# HTML5 Server Side Events - display

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking at this http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse tutorial and have a question about display of data. Right now the new data always getting displayed in next line and I want to know how to display new data in first line and previous data in next line (reverse of). please let me know if any code sample that will be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of *adding* the new data to the result `div` contents like this...

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
```

...we *replace* the result `div` contents with the new data AND it's old contents.

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data + "<br>" + document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
```

You can paste this in their [try it](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse) window to see it working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Getting server updates</h1>
        <div id="result"></div>

        <script>
            if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
                var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
                source.onmessage = function(event) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data + "<br>" + document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
                };
            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has worked. Great ! For the same above code, while waiting on server responses like every 3 seconds and in between if I have to show 'loading' animation gif then how to do that

Comment: I would just put the loader on the page all the time in this case. There is really no time between the waiting and displaying periods where there would be a discernible difference. Maybe something [like this](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/igHbG) right above the result div. That would indicate to the user to expect the new information above the current information.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion . one question I have is the above code will display server sent messages continuously and if I want to restrict to show only 10 recent messages all the time and not more than that. please let me know

Comment: I did posted separated question.

Comment: Here is the link to that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776808/displaying-of-only-10-recent-server-sent-event-messages-all-the-time