# Displaying of only 10 recent Server Sent Event Messages all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse), I was able to alter their script to run in reverse, showing the lastest event at the top of the list:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Getting server updates</h1>
        <div id="result"></div>

        <script>
            if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
                var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
                source.onmessage = function(event) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data + "<br>" + document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
                };
            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How would I limit this to the 10 most recent message events only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paste this in their [try it](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse) window to see it working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Getting server updates</h1>
        <div id="result"></div>

        <script>
            messages = new Array();

            if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
                var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
                source.onmessage = function(event) {
                    if (messages.length == 10) messages.splice(-1, 1);
                    messages.splice(0, 0, event.data);
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = messages.join("<br />");
                };
            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890111/streaming-of-html-data-table